# How to perform iterative calculations while working on an excel file (hssfworkbook) in scala?

Tags: excel, scala, hssf

Needed to perform iterative calculation over circular references (condition where formula refers to its own cell either directly or indirectly) while creating an excel (using HSSFWorkbook) in scala. Found one of the probable solutions - https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/IterationRecord.html#setIteration-boolean- , but was not able to implement it over hssfworkbook.
Please suggest me any alternatives/ solution to the above mentioned issue.
Thanks

Comment: Please, add some details on your use case and some code you are trying to use.